# Identify / Classify images based on certain characteristics such as white spots or temperature at different pixels of the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am working on a use case where a bunch of images devices on field are provided. Some of the images have bad devices, and some of them have good images. This data has to be stored on hadoop. I have been trying to identify the images with bad devices based on certain criteria such as "white spots" in the image using OpenCv-Python libraries.
However, it is not giving accurate results. Which algorithm, and software package would be good to do image classification in above scenario.

Here is what I am planning to try, but looking for guidance so that I don't tread the wrong path too far.

1. Use Open-cv with python API, tried to load images as spark RDDs of numpy arrays.
2. Get SIFT keys for images and use them as features. Apply SVM algorithm to classify the images with good devices vs images with bad devices ( I am new to Open-CV)

(or)

Use tensorflow and build a convolutional neural network to classify the images into the ones with good devices & bad devices (I am completely new to this.)

I also have to identify the GPS coordinates of these images, which may be possible using FLIR software. Does anyone know if there is an open source version of this package. Found libFLIR but don't have any examples on how to use.

Comment: What are bad devices? Is it something similar to image artifacts? What qualifies as a good image?

Comment: @Anton, these are images of solar panels in a solar farm. Each image will have a bunch of solar panels. I have 1000 such images. I want to create a 5 clusters from 1000 images where each cluster has x number of images( I am told that there can be 4 different types of issues with these panels). Can I use k-means to do this ?

Comment: Please provide representative sample images, both unmarked and marked to clarify your regions of interest - else it is hard to guess.

Comment: @Mark, unfortunately I cannot share the images. However, an answer to this question will help me:   "How to extract features (BagOfWords, BagOfFeatures etc.,) from a bunch of images so that those features can be used to create clusters using k-means clustering algorithm.